# How to evaluate $\int_0^1 \left\{ {\frac{1}{x}} \right\}^2 \, dx$

Tags: integration

How to evaluate $$\int_0^1 \left\{ {\frac{1}{x}} \right\}^2 \, dx \text{ ?}$$

Here $\{x\}$ means the fractional part of $x.$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$$\frac1{s-1}- \frac{\zeta(s)}{s}=\int_1^\infty \{x\} x^{-s-1}dx=  \int_1^\infty (\int_1^x \{y\}dy) (s+1)x^{-s-2}dx$$ $$=
(s+1)\int_1^\infty (\frac12 (\lfloor x\rfloor-1)+\frac12\{x\}^2) x^{-2-s}dx$$ $$=\frac12(\zeta(s+1)-1)+\frac12(s+1)\int_1^\infty \{x\}^2 x^{-2-s}dx$$

$$\int_0^1 \{1/x\}^2dx=\int_1^\infty \{x\}^2 x^{-2}dx= 2\lim_{s\to 0}\frac1{s-1}- \frac{\zeta(s)}{s}-\frac12(\zeta(s+1)-1)$$ $$=-1-\gamma-2\zeta'(0)=-1-\gamma+\log(2\pi)$$

Answer (score 2):

\begin{align}
\int_0^1{\left\{ {\frac{1}{x}} \right\}^2 \mathrm{d}x}
&= \sum_{n=1}^\infty \int_{1/(n+1)}^{1/n}{\left\{ {\frac{1}{x}} \right\}^2 \mathrm{d}x} \\
&= \sum_{n=1}^\infty \int_{1/(n+1)}^{1/n}{\left( {\frac{1}{x}-n} \right)^2 \mathrm{d}x} \\
&= \sum_{n=1}^\infty \int_{1/(n+1)}^{1/n}{\left( {\frac{1}{x^2}-\frac{2n}{x}+n^2} \right) \mathrm{d}x} \\ 
&= \sum_{n=1}^\infty \left.\left(-\frac{1}{x}-2n \log x+n^2 x \right)\right|_{1/(n+1)}^{1/n} \\
&= \sum_{n=1}^\infty \left(-n+2n \log n + \frac{n^2}{n} + (n+1)-2n \log(n+1)-\frac{n^2}{n+1} \right) \\
&= \sum_{n=1}^\infty \left(1+2n \log \frac{n}{n+1} + \frac{n}{n+1} \right) \\
&\approx 0.259
\end{align}

Comment: This should simplify somewhat to $\ln{(2\pi)}-\gamma-1$

Comment: Yes, maybe via summation by parts, with $\gamma=\sum_{n=1}^\infty (1/n-\log(1+1/n))$